# Remove tasks and index when creating a menu tab from views

Tags: 7, views, theming

I am using views to create a menu tab for my views page and it works fine accept it comes with two unexpected tabs: Tasks and Index, which are showed in the photo below. Is there any way to remove them? Thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this using [hook_menu_local_tasks_alter](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_menu_local_tasks_alter/7.x) hook.

> Alter tabs and actions displayed on the page before they are rendered.

```
function hide_tabs_menu_local_tasks_alter(&$data) {
    foreach ($data['tabs'][0]['output'] as $key => $value) {
        if ($value['#link']['path'] == "check your path") {
          unset($data['tabs'][0]['output'][$key]);
        }
    }
}
```

You can also take a look on [Tab Tamer](https://www.drupal.org/project/tabtamer) module.

> Tab Tamer is an administration utility that provides easy re-ordering,
>   hiding, and deactivation of tabs and subtabs. You can also rename tab
>   labels.
>
> Tab Tamer makes use of Drupal's drag ordering, but degrades gracefully
>   when javascript is disabled.
>
> Tab Tamer utilizes Drupal's cache system to help conserve server
>   resources.

Comment: Ok. Thanks for your reply. Could you please explain abit more details of how can I add the hook?

Comment: you can create a custom module or can place it on themes template.php file.

Comment: Read https://www.drupal.org/node/295381

Comment: I have made a module  to hide the Tasks tab but it is not working. This is the code `function remove_tab_menu_local_tasks_alter(&$data) {
    foreach ($data['tabs'][0]['output'] as $key => $value) {
        if ($value['#link']['path'] == "/admin") {
          unset($data['tabs'][0]['output'][$key]);
        }
    }
}`